# @ManyToOne not filling the parent id field

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a many-to-one bidirectionnal relationship between a parent and child entity. The problem is, when i'm persisting the child, the `parent_id` isn't persisted. The other fields are fine, but `parent_id` stay at `NULL`. I'm using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and mapstruct to convert between entity and dto, if that can help.

The java files are the following :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent_entity", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<Child> children;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class ChildEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "parent_entity_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent_entity;
}
```

I already tried a bunch of answers from SO, but to no avail for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using bidirectional relationship, you are now responsible to set a parent for your child. And remove `insertable = false`.

Comment: Thanks ! That was it. The `insertable = false` and the assignment... Though i'm sure i tried t he two together before, I probably missed another problem that was solved along the trials.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. You have to add each other in both parent and child. Only adding children to the list does not seem to work.

Try it out, and see if that fixes the problem.